# Haskell Parenthesis Matching for Find and Replace

Tags: regex, parsing, haskell, replace, parentheses

I am currently writing a Haskell program where, at some point, I need to manipulate Haskell code someone else has entered into the system by augmenting it with my own information and functions. For example, I may wish to find all places the user has written something like:

a = Shape(Rectangle 3 5)

And alter these entries with additional data (for example, the line number they appeared on, or information about the user who wrote them:

a = TrackedShape(74 "John" (Rectangle 3 5))

In order to do this find and replace, I have tried just using regular expressions, but have found that in many cases they are not expressive enough to capture all use cases. In particular for the example above I would need to capture everything contained within the shape constructor and so would need to know what the matching parentheses are.

I have also tried to see if a parser such as [haskell-src-exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts) would be of use to me, but I am unsure. It seems that, while these sorts of libraries may be good for parsing Haskell code initially, they lack the ability to parse the code, alter the parse tree, then change the parsed code *back* to its original form while retaining the structure of the original text.

Are there any libraries that would be useful for this sort of task? Or, failing that, is there some sort of function I could write that would provide a robust search and replace for this?

Answer (score 5):

When you are using Haskell and regexes fail you, then reach for Parsec! I personally find this to be one of the best features of Haskell that I miss when working in other languages, that parsing context-free languages or even context sensitive languages is as easy, or even easier, than working with regular expressions.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Control.Applicative ((<$>),(<*>),(*>),(<*))
import Control.Monad
import Text.Printf

-- Handy helper to concat successive parsers that return strings
infixl 4 <++>
f <++> g = (++) <$> f <*> g

-- Parse a balanced number of brackets
brackets :: Parser String
brackets = string "(" <++> (join <$> many brackets) <++> string ")" <|> many1 (noneOf "()")

-- Parser that will perform your example replace
replaceShape :: Int -> String -> Parser String
replaceShape line name = printf "TrackedShape (%i \"%s\" %s)" line name <$> (string "Shape " *> brackets)
```

Test in GHCi:

```
> parseTest (replaceShape 10 "John") "Shape (Rectangle 3 5)"
"TrackedShape (10 \"John\" (Rectangle 3 5))"
```

The code above may look relatively impenetrable if you have not worked with Applicatives or even Applicative parsers before. However, like regular expressions, once you get used to it it is a great way of working. There are lots of very complete parser tutorials out there, and Learn you a Haskell has some great explanation of Applicatives. `<$>` is an infix version of fmap, and `<*>` joins together expressions in a similar (but less powerful) way to `>>=`. So the expression `(++) <$> f <*> g` in our case is equivalent to

```
do
    a <- f
    b <- g
    return $ a ++ b
```

In fact, the function could have been written this way (there is an Applicative and Monad interface), but the applicative style allows for very succinct, regex like parsers.

The other functions used in the example are `<|>` which provides alternation (ie parse in this way or that way. So in the brackets example the two alternatives are open a new bracket or parse something in the middle that isn't a bracket.) and `<*` and `*>`, which are like `<*>` except they discard a result from one of the sides. the < points to the result which is kept.

Note that I have note implemented the extra functionality to detect line numbers, but Parsec can do this as the parser monad is in fact a monad transformer and so can be put on top of a state monad to retain arbitrary information during a parse. Parsec has a very rich feature set for doing things like this, so it is definitely the tool you want for this job.

Comment: "because any Applicative gives rise to a Monad"

Uh... pretty sure that's not true.

Comment: Whoops, wrong way around! I've actually removed the comment as I don't think it was especially helpful at that point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

haskell-src-exts does have a printer for code: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.14.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Pretty.html  When you say retaining the structure, do you mean retain the original locations of line breaks?

The default `parseFile` function in this module http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.14.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Annotated.html does give you the original source information, so theoretically you could retain that information during the manipulation and then use it in the printing.  I suspect you may get away with only using the line numbers to introduce line breaks (and following indent) at the appropriate points, with the spacing within a line relatively standard.

One problem is that you will lose the comments in the source when you parse it.  The only way I can think to avoid this is to parse it, and try to use the original source locations to decide where to modify the original file (rather than spitting it out again from the parsed form).  But in general parsing code and retaining all the comments (incl inline comments) in a manageable form is quite a tricky task, and one you often don't find libraries for.

Comment: Yes, to clarify. When I say "retaining structure" I mean retaining indentation, line breaks etc. The replacements I make on screen will appear to the user immediately, so I don't want it to suddenly destroy all their indentation. I want it to look like *their* code which happens to have been augmented

Comment: Perhaps you do write an extremely simple parser (using parsec or attoparsec), which just parses parentheses and text. Then you could apply reqular expressions to whatever is contained within parens.

Answer (score 1):

[megaparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec) parsers are aware
of line numbers, and the [replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec) package allows you to
search for pattern matches and then edit the found matches. Here is a solution using 
[`Replace.Megaparsec.streamEdit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:streamEdit).

```hs
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char

let pattern :: Parsec Void String (Int,String)
    pattern = do
        string "Shape("
        lineNumber <- unPos <$> sourceLine <$> getSourcePos
        parenInner <- many $ noneOf ")"
        string ")"
        return (lineNumber, parenInner)

let editor (lineNumber, parenInner) =
        "TrackedShape(" ++
        show lineNumber ++
        " \"John\" (" ++
        parenInner ++
        "))"
```

```hs
>>> streamEdit pattern editor "a = Shape(Rectangle 3 5)"
"a = TrackedShape(1 \"John\" (Rectangle 3 5))"
```